# Sharing data between a service and a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to share data between a service and a controller in AngularJS.
I've read about it and my code should work but it doesn't.

This is my controller:

```
function udpController($scope,$interval,udpService) {
    $scope.status = udpService.status;
    $interval(function(){udpService.changeStatus();},2500);
}
```

And this is my service:

```
angular.module('udpTest').service('udpService' ,function() {
        var self = this;
        this.status;

        this.changeStatus = function() {
                self.status = Math.random();
        }
}
```

The `$scope.status` doesn't change at all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value first and the function that is called in $interval does not know that the value of $scope.status is to be updated. So you need to include that inside the function like this:

```
function udpController($scope,$interval,udpService) {

    $interval(function(){
       udpService.changeStatus();
       $scope.status = udpService.status;
   },2500);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You `$scope` value is already updated to `undefined`, coz the `$interval` is called after all the functions in the stack.

```
$interval(function(){udpService.changeStatus();},2500);
```

Change this below:

```
$interval(function(){udpService.changeStatus();$scope.status =udpService.status; },2500);
```

Again if `udpService.changeStatus();` is an async call, it would be much better to use `$q` service with `promises` `(resolved, rejected)`;

Comment: But changeStatus(); returns nothing, it just changes the variable value.

Comment: So you just need to use $interval(function(){$scope.status = udpService.changeStatus();},2500);

Comment: assumes `changeStatus()` returns something but it doesn't return anything

Comment: This will give undefined as the service function does not return anything

Comment: @NirTzezana: Change this to... $interval(function(){udpService.changeStatus();$scope.status =udpService.status; },2500);

Comment: `$scope.status = udpService.changeStatus() // undefined` there is no `return` in service method